# Using Java API in Scala to query views in Couchbase throws timeout exception

Tags: java, couchbase

EDIT: Note that this works perfectly in java 1.6 but fails in java 1.7.

I've been struggling to get the Couchbase 2.0 java API to work with views.  It works perfectly for getting and putting keys into a bucket.

When I run the scala code below using Java 1.7, I get the following exception:

```
scala> ERROR com.couchbase.client.ViewNode$EventLogger:  Connection timed out: [localhost/127.0.0.1:8092(closed)]
```

I've also tried setting the timeout in the connection builder to no avail.

```
    import java.net.URI
    import com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
    val uris = List(URI.create("http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools"))
    val client = new CouchbaseClient(uris, "test", "")
    val view = client.asyncGetView("date", "dates")
```

However, the python code below works perfectly, connects to the view, and has the right output:

```
    from couchbase.client import Couchbase
    client = Couchbase("localhost:8091", "username", "password")
    bucket = client["test"]
    view = bucket.view("_design/date/_view/dates")
    count = 0
    for row in view:
        count = count + 1
    print(count)
```

Any ideas how to properly connect?  I've tried to copy their examples exactly in my code. Unfortunately using python is not an option for this project.

Answer (score 1):

we are aware of this issue (http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/JCBC-151).

It's not your fault or scalas, its just that our client currently has some problems to connect with java 7. If this is fixed, I'm sure your code will work as expected.

Comment: Any further information on this topic? Perhaps a work-around or a new release of the Java client library? I see there is a new JAR for the recent release but I could not find any in maven, perhaps that JAR resolves the issue..?

Comment: Jar found, turns out the repository changed but almost all of the documentation still points to the old repository. For the next person, you can update your repositories to "mvnrepository" at "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/" and with the dependency as "com.couchbase.client" % "couchbase-client" % "1.2.0". Error is gone in updated Jar.

Comment: That is correct, we moved to maven central (and updated the couchbase.com docs accordingly). Where did you find outdated info?

Comment: Btw, we are already on 1.2.1 and 1.2.2 will be out soon with some more bugfixes for the 1.2.x branch!

Comment: The documentation has been updated since I read it with the correct maven information (in the xml example). The sbt documentation still refers to the old dependency, ie. libraryDependencies += "couchbase" % "couchbase-client" % "1.2.1" should read "com.couchbase.client" % "couchbase-client" % "1.2.1". Also, the earlier version "1.2.0" didn't work in sbt unless you used a val to define the couchbase version, otherwise the resolver dropped the trailing ".0" and couldn't find the resource url. I think I'll wait for the 1.2.2 version if you tell me there are bugs in 1.2.1, thanks for the info

Comment: The github readme is also not updated, https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client. And the maven repository does not show the 1.2.1 version you mentioned: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.couchbase.client/couchbase-client